# PyQt4 QSpinBox value format

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qwidget, qspinbox

My objective is to use a `QSpinBox` to display the numbers from **0 to 9999 with the increasement of 1** using 4-digits format.

I managed to set the Maximum value 9999 by using `setMaximum` command. But I can't seems to find a way to display the values in 4digits format (eg. 0000, 0001,0002). Whenever i set the value to **0000**  using `setValue` , the SpinBox display as **0**.

How do i display the numbers in 4-digits format (i.e adding leading zero as required) in `QSpinBox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a custom QSpinBox, overriding **textFromValue**:

```
class MySpinBox(QtGui.QSpinBox):
    def __init__(self, *args):
       QtGui.QSpinBox.__init__(self, *args)

       self.setRange(0,9999)

    def textFromValue(self, value):
       return "%04d" % value
```

Comment: Does that mean there is no direct method to set how the values are being displayed other than inheriting from QSpinBox class?

Comment: To my knowledge this is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want, just set the "prefix" attribute of the spinbox widget to "000". This will then pad values to be 0001, 0002, etc.

Comment: This won't give a 4-digit format for values greater than 9. It will just add the same prefix to every value: i.e. `99 -> 00099`, `999 -> 000999`, etc.